# java.lang.VerifyError: org/fest/assertions/internal/Objects

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium, fest, spoon

I am trying to run android tests
using [Spoon](http://square.github.io/spoon/) framework and robotium solo

And their test project which is found [here](https://github.com/square/spoon)

This is the test

```
package com.example.spoon.ordering.tests;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import com.robotium.solo.Solo;
import com.squareup.spoon.Spoon;
import com.example.spoon.ordering.OrderActivity;

import static org.fest.assertions.api.ANDROID.assertThat;

public class OrderActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<OrderActivity> {
  public OrderActivityTest() {
    super(OrderActivity.class);
  }

  private OrderActivity activity;
  private Solo solo;

  @Override protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    activity = getActivity();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), activity);
  }

  public void testMakeASandwich_ItTastesGood() {
    Button nextButton = (Button) solo.getText("Next");

    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "initial_state");

    assertThat(nextButton).isDisabled();
    solo.clickOnText("Sandwich");
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "selected_sandwich");
    assertThat(nextButton).isEnabled();

    solo.clickOnView(nextButton);
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "bread");

    assertThat(nextButton).isDisabled();
    solo.clickOnText("Wheat");
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "selected_bread");
    assertThat(nextButton).isEnabled();

    solo.clickOnView(nextButton);
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "meats");

    assertThat(nextButton).isEnabled();
    solo.clickOnText("Turkey");
    solo.clickOnText("Roast Beef");
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "selected_meats");

    solo.clickOnView(nextButton);
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "veggies");

    assertThat(nextButton).isEnabled();
    solo.clickOnText("Lettuce");
    solo.clickOnText("Tomato");
    solo.clickOnText("Cucumbers");
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "selected_veggies");

    solo.clickOnView(nextButton);
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "cheeses");

    assertThat(nextButton).isEnabled();
    solo.clickOnText("American");
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "selected_cheeses");

    solo.clickOnView(nextButton);
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "toasted");

    CheckedTextView toastedNo = (CheckedTextView) solo.getText("No");
    assertThat(toastedNo).isChecked();
    assertThat(nextButton).isEnabled();

    solo.clickOnView(nextButton);
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "your_info");

    assertThat(nextButton).isDisabled();
    solo.typeText(0, "Trent Sondag");
    solo.typeText(1, "bearfight@example.com");
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "completed_your_info");
    assertThat(nextButton).isEnabled();

    solo.clickOnView(nextButton);
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "review");
  }

  public void testMakeSomeSalad_ItIsHealthy() {
    Button nextButton = (Button) solo.getText("Next");

    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "initial_state");

    assertThat(nextButton).isDisabled();
    solo.clickOnText("Salad");
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "selected_salad");
    assertThat(nextButton).isEnabled();

    solo.clickOnView(nextButton);
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "salad_type");

    assertThat(nextButton).isDisabled();
    solo.clickOnText("Caesar");
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "selected_salad_type");
    assertThat(nextButton).isEnabled();

    solo.clickOnView(nextButton);
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "dressing");

    CheckedTextView dressingNone = (CheckedTextView) solo.getText("No dressing");
    assertThat(dressingNone).isChecked();
    assertThat(nextButton).isEnabled();

    solo.clickOnView(nextButton);
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "your_info");

    assertThat(nextButton).isDisabled();
    solo.typeText(0, "Trent Sondag");
    solo.typeText(1, "bearfight@example.com");
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "completed_your_info");
    assertThat(nextButton).isEnabled();

    solo.clickOnView(nextButton);
    Spoon.screenshot(activity, "review");
  }
}
```

The problem is the test fails with these errors, and I don't know how to fix it.

```
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164): failed: testMakeSomeSalad_ItIsHealthy(com.example.spoon.ordering.tests.OrderActivityTest)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164): ----- begin exception -----
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164): java.lang.VerifyError: org/fest/assertions/internal/Objects
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at org.fest.assertions.api.AbstractAssert.<init>(AbstractAssert.java:43)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at org.fest.assertions.api.android.view.AbstractViewAssert.<init>(AbstractViewAssert.java:27)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at org.fest.assertions.api.android.widget.AbstractTextViewAssert.<init>(AbstractTextViewAssert.java:14)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at org.fest.assertions.api.android.widget.TextViewAssert.<init>(TextViewAssert.java:12)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at org.fest.assertions.api.ANDROID.assertThat(ANDROID.java:1020)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at com.example.spoon.ordering.tests.OrderActivityTest.testMakeSomeSalad_ItIsHealthy(OrderActivityTest.java:93)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at com.example.spoon.ordering.tests.SpoonInstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(SpoonInstrumentationTestRunner.java:36)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164):    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
08-31 14:53:47.021: I/TestRunner(12164): ----- end exception -----
08-31 14:53:47.025: I/TestRunner(12164): finished: testMakeSomeSalad_ItIsHealthy(com.example.spoon.ordering.tests.OrderActivityTest)
```

I added these libraries to the test project
[image]

How to fix it ?